# Debugging Scribble's (need a pre-part for decode) error

Tags: racket, scribble

Consider the following Scribble document:

```
#lang scribble/manual

@title[#:tag "MyTitle"]{MyTitle}

@(module bq racket/base
    (require scribble/html/html)
    (provide blockquote))
@(require 'bq)

@blockquote{
   "Ho, ho, ho! -- Santa Claus."
}
```

If I try building this with `scribble --dest . test.scrbl`, it fails with

```
/Users/varun/Code/test.scrbl:10:0: not valid in document body (need a pre-part for decode) in: (element 'blockquote '() '("\"Ho, ho, ho! -- Santa Claus.\"") #f)
  context...:
   body of "/Users/varun/Code/test.scrbl"
   .../private/map.rkt:40:19: loop
   .../racket/cmdline.rkt:191:51
   body of "/Applications/Racket v8.0/share/pkgs/scribble-lib/scribble/run.rkt"
```

I don't understand the error. What "pre-part" is it referring to? I found a blog post ["Writing a paper in Scribble"](https://prl.ccs.neu.edu/blog/2019/02/17/writing-a-paper-with-scribble/) which describes a similar error; there, the problem is that a number isn't converted to a string. However, I do have a string here, so I don't understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what Sam said in his answer, as well as a [similar comment on Twitter](https://twitter.com/wilbowma/status/1469393585518743552), I ended up defining a blockquote as:

```
@(require scribble/core scribble/decode)
@(define (blockquote . strs)
      (make-nested-flow (make-style "blockquote" '(command))
                        (decode-flow strs)))
```

(Source: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/flock-lab/flock/-/blob/docs/main.scrbl?L9-L11)

This can be used without quotes:

```
@blockquote{Ho, ho, ho! -- Santa Claus.}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `scribble/html` is not connected to `scribble/manual`, and the "element" constructed there is an HTML element. You can't use the functions from `scribble/html` in a document like this.

If you want a block quote in scribble, you probably want to use `nested-flow`.